# Parallelizing a Dask aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Building off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080171/constructing-mode-and-corresponding-count-functions-using-custom-aggregation-fun), I implemented the custom mode formula, but have found issues with performance on this function. Essentially, when I enter into this aggregation, my cluster only uses one of my threads, which is not great for performance. I am doing calculations on over 150 attributes (mostly categorical data) across 16k rows, which I think I can split up into individual threads/processes and throw back together into a single dataframe later on. Note that this aggregation has to be on two columns so I might be getting worse performance for not being able to use a single column as an index.

Is there a way to incorporate dask futures or parallel processing into the aggregate calculation?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
from pandas import DataFrame

def chunk(s):
    return s.value_counts()

def agg(s):
    s = s._selected_obj
    return s.groupby(level=list(range(s.index.nlevels))).sum()

def finalize(s):
    # s is a multi-index series of the form (group, value): count. First
    # manually group on the group part of the index. The lambda will receive a
    # sub-series with multi index. Next, drop the group part from the index.
    # Finally, determine the index with the maximum value, i.e., the mode.
    level = list(range(s.index.nlevels - 1))
    return (
        s.groupby(level=level)
        .apply(lambda s: s.reset_index(level=level, drop=True).argmax())
    )

def main() -> DataFrame:
    client = Client('scheduler:8786')

    ddf = dd.read_csv('/sample/data.csv')
    custom_mode = dd.Aggregation('custom mode', chunk, agg, finalize)
    result = ddf.groupby(['a','b']).agg(custom_mode).compute()
    return result
```

Side note, I am using Docker to spin up my scheduler and workers using the daskdev/dask (2.18.1) docker image.

Comment: Does section 2 of this article: `Using dask ‘delayed’ in a loop` help?: https://pythonhealthcare.org/2018/11/25/99-parallel-processing-functions-and-loops-with-dask-delayed-method/#:~:text=Parallel%20processing%20functions%20and%20loops%20with%20dask%20'delayed'%20method,-Michael%20Allen%20Miscellaneous&text=Dask%20is%20a%20Python%20library,to%20speed%20up%20the%20program.

Comment: yes thanks David. I split up the aggregation to loop through the columns  in the dataframe and then used the delay functionality to parallelize it.

Comment: Thanks @BrendonGallagher, would you be able to answer your own question with updated code? I might like to do something similar to this in the future and this would be a good reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used futures to essentially parallelize the aggregation for each column. Since I had so many columns, passing each aggregation to its own worker thread saved me a bunch of time. Thanks to David for his comments as well as [the article on parallel workloads from the dask documentation](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html)!

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from pandas import DataFrame

def chunk(s):
    return s.value_counts()

def agg(s):
    s = s._selected_obj
    return s.groupby(level=list(range(s.index.nlevels))).sum()

def finalize(s):
    level = list(range(s.index.nlevels - 1))
    return (
        s.groupby(level=level)
        .apply(lambda s: s.reset_index(level=level, drop=True).idxmax())
    )

def delayed_mode(ddf, groupby, col, custom_agg):
    return ddf.groupby(groupby).agg({col: custom_agg}).compute()

def main() -> DataFrame:
    client = Client('scheduler:8786')

    ddf = dd.read_csv('/sample/data.csv')
    custom_mode = dd.Aggregation('custom mode', chunk, agg, finalize)

    futures = []

    for col in multiple_trimmed.columns:
        future = client.submit(delayed_mode, ddf, ["a", "b"], col, custom_mode_dask)
        futures.append(future)

    ddfs = client.gather(futures)
    result = pd.concat(ddfs, axis=1)
    return result
```