# Number of Unique values in Dask-Dataframe columns

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask Dataframe read from csv file having around 1 million records and 120 features/columns and I would like to count the number of unique value in each column. I can clearly do it for each column separately using the for-loop:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
dask_df = dd.read_csv("train.csv")
for column in dask_df.columns:
     print(dask_df[col].nunique().compute())
```

But compute at each iteration is very expensive ( took me around ~40minutes with 3 node cluster with 5 workers with each worker having 2GB of memory and 2 vcores), so is there a way where I can get the unique values at each column of data-frame? I have tried **dask_df.describe()** api but that gives unique values only for String types. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another workaround, where the number of unique values for each column are all calculated at once, allowing for more opportunity for optimization:

```py
import random
import pandas
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "x": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
    "y": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
    "z": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

unique = {
    name: ddf[name].nunique()
    for name in ddf.columns
}

# traverse=True is default, but being explicit that we are traversing the dict for dask objects
dask.compute(unique, traverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the fastest solution, but you can use [`.melt()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.melt.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.melt) to unpivot your dataframe columns and then use [`.groupby()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.groupby.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.groupby) on the variable column to count the unique values in each group in order to get significant performance improvement over your column per column solution:

```py
dd.read_csv('test.csv').melt().groupby('variable')['value'].nunique().compute()
```

Let us generate some random integer data and save as csv:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd

nrows = 10000
ncols = 120

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)
random_data = rng.integers(low=0, high=nrows/2, size=(nrows,ncols))
pd.DataFrame(data=random_data).add_prefix('col_').to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

We use the following two functions for performance evaluation:

```py
def nunique_per_column():
    dask_df = dd.read_csv('test.csv')
    counts = []
    for col in dask_df.columns:
          counts.append(dask_df[col].nunique().compute())
    return pd.Series(counts, index=dask_df.columns)

def melt_groupby_nunique():
    return dd.read_csv('test.csv').melt().groupby('variable')['value'].nunique().compute()
```

First check if both functions compute the same result with:

```py
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(nunique_per_column().sort_index(),
                               melt_groupby_nunique().sort_index(),
                               check_names=False)
```

`%timeit` on the functions and the sample data yields the following output on my machine:

```py
%timeit nunique_per_column()
17.5 s ± 216 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit melt_groupby_nunique()
1.78 s ± 576 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: When I tried running using melt(), seems like workers consumes a lot of memory but there is a slight improvement at performance, what about using dask_df.compute().nunique() as this is faster than all of them (took ~30 seconds) but compute() will require entire dataframe to fit in memory?

Comment: if your dataframe fits into memory you can use pd.DataFrame.nunique() after you called compute(). However `nunique()` is not available for dask dataframes and you have use groupby. Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45922884/14333932).

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed as of Dask version `2022.01.0`, `dask.DataFrame.nunique()` has been [implemented](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8479):

```py
import random
import pandas
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "x": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
    "y": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
    "z": [random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)],
})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

ddf.nunique().compute()
```

Comment: That's cool, will check it out and upvote this!